# UITabBarController delegate methods never get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I'm currently refactoring my iPad application and instead of a button on the NavigationBar, I would like to put my Logout button as a TabBar button item.

All of my views are in a unique StoryBoard so I get my TabBar in my Appdelegate.m by this way :

```
// Add logout tab to tabbar
storyboard                      = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabbar      = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
[tabbar setDelegate:self];
```

Of course the delegate protocol is declared in my Appdelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

After that, I create an empty viewController in order to create my logout tab :

```
UIViewController *logout        = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
```

Then I get tabbar viewControllers as NSMutableArray and add my logout VC :

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tabbar viewControllers]];

[viewControllers addObject:logout];
```

Finally I set tabbar viewControllers with my new array :

```
[tabbar setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

I think that those steps are correct. 
So why does the didSelectViewController is not called when I change the displayed tab ?

If it can help, here's my didSelectViewController method (which is write in AppDelegate.m)

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"onglet sélectionné : %d / %d", [tabBarController selectedIndex], [[tabBarController viewControllers]count]);
    //select the index where your logout button is
    if ([tabBarController selectedIndex] == [[tabBarController viewControllers]count]-1) {
        NSLog(@"logout");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: [Swift answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861294/3681880)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put `[self setDelegate:self];` in your ViewDidLoad or somewhere where the object get's initialized

Comment: You mean set the delegate in an other viewController ?

EDIT
I ask this because currently all the code you see above in my post is in Appdelegate.m and this file does not have viewDidLoad method

Comment: It works ! I set the delegate in an other viewController and the method gets called

Answer (score -2):

try intialising the tabbar object;

```
// Add logout tab to tabbar
storyboard                      = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabbar      = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabbar      = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
[tabbar setDelegate:self];
```