# Swift: How to execute an action when UITabBarItem is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Currently I have a Tab Bar Controller that is connected to a tableview controller. I'm trying to go to the top of the tableview when I press the tab bar item. I know how to get to the top of the tableview. I just don't know how to do an action when the item is pressed.

Answer (score 37):

You should use `UITabBarDelegate` with method `didSelectItem`. Use it as any standard delegate:

```
class yourclass: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        //This method will be called when user changes tab.
    }
}
```

And do not forget to set your tab bar delegate to `self` in view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can we set tab bar delegate to self?

Comment: tabBar.delegate = self 
If it helps you now or someone else in case.

Answer (score 21):

[Here is an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378652/open-viewcontroller-from-tab-like-in-instagram-camera-page-on-ios/30379403#30379403)

Basically you do this:

- Make sure your view controller is subscribed to the UITabBarDelegate
- Set tags in IB for each tab bar item
- Implement the didSelectItem method, something like this:

  ```
  -(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
      if(item.tag == 1) {
         // Code for item 1
      }
      else if(item.tag == 2) {
         // Code for item 2
      }
  }
  ```

This will give you access to each tab item tapped event. Hope it helps!

In Swift:

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if(item.tag == 1) {
        // Code for item 1
    } else if(item.tag == 2) {
        // Code for item 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

SWIFT 3

```
class yourclass: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print("Test")
    }
}
```

And do not forget to set your tabBar delegate to self in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    <YOUR TAB BAR NAME>.delegate = self 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it is vey help to me

Answer (score 11):

I was having trouble implementing the other answers here. This is a fuller answer. It assumes you are using a `UITabBarController` (the default if you create a new Tabbed App). This solution will print a message every time a view controller tab button is tapped.

[image]

## Code

Create a new Swift file called **MyTabBarController.swift**. Paste in the following code.

```
import UIKit

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // tell our UITabBarController subclass to handle its own delegate methods
        self.delegate = self
    }

    // called whenever a tab button is tapped
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        if viewController is FirstViewController {
            print("First tab")
        } else if viewController is SecondViewController {
            print("Second tab")
        }
    }
}
```

## Interface Builder

On your storyboard select the Tab Bar Controller. Then in the Identity inspector, set the class name to `MyTabBarController` (that is, the name of the class in the code above).

[image]

That's all. You can run your app now and be notified whenever the user taps a tab bar item.

## Notes

- If you need to run a method on a tap, then you can do something like the following in `didSelect` method.

  ```
  if let firstVC = viewController as? FirstViewController {
      firstVC.doSomeAction()
  }
  ```
- You could do make the `FirstViewController` implement the delegate and handle everything there. That way you wouldn't need to make any custom `UITabBarController` subclass and set it in IB. However, having a child do the parent's work seems like the wrong place to do it. Anyway, here is is:

  ```
  class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          tabBarController?.delegate = self
      }

      func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

  The `didSelect` method above gets called no matter which tab is tapped.
- [`UITabBarControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate) documentation

Comment: Thanks for `tabBarController` method. The accepted answer was using `tabBar` method instead, and seems to work on ViewController, but not on TabBarController

Answer (score 5):

An alternate solution is to just do something in `viewDidAppear` in whichever View Controller the tab shows.

**First Tab View Controller**

```
import UIKit
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("First tab")
    }
}
```

**Second Tab View Controller**

```
import UIKit
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("Second tab")
    }
}
```

Comment: So much more elegant, with the required code sitting in the appropriate ViewController. Thank you Suragch.

Comment: This is a much simpler solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: this will break if we push a controller on root controller of any tabbar item and then pop it. since we dont want to execute code at that point

Answer (score 1):

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController,UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabbar: UITabBar!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabbar.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print(tabBar.items![1]) // The number is tab index
    }
}
```